# Daily review tasks don't warn about full edit queues, but editing the question directly does?

Tags: support, bug

Whenever I try to do my daily review tasks on SO, and I see a newcomer ask a very poorly written question. I invest a lot of time to understand what they're trying to ask and then rewrite it with proper grammar and simplicity.

Only then to do I get prompted with the following warning: [image]

This is very discouraging to continue reviewing questions. Whenever I go directly to the question and I hit `Edit` at least I get blocked from actually going into the editor view in the first place.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure if wasn't a case of that the edit queue *did* have space when you started editing, and then was full by the time you finished? (Also, note you only need ~40 more reputation and you avoid the edit queue entirely.)

Comment: Very sure, I still have the question open and even after refreshing the page, I can still edit and it opens up the editor view: https://i.imgur.com/w5W6u4j.png
https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/31800732

Comment: Cross-site duplicate on MSE: [Disable 'Edit' option in new review queues if you have too many pending suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370543/348196)